# How can I make my PC hibernate when idle?

Tags: 11.10, hibernate

My Ubuntu 11.10 desktop has an option to suspend when inactive (under System Settings > Power) but no option to hibernate.   How can I hibernate it after a period of inactivity?

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine since its a desktop it sleeps instead of hibernates, it looks like laptop users have the opposite problem,

[Sleep Instead of Hibernate When Idle](http://lifehacker.com/5642254/make-ubuntu-hibernate-instead-of-sleep)

So for your case we would change the value for "sleep_type_ac" to hibernate when following the article. Hope this does the trick.

Simplified steps:

1. Open a terminal, and run `gconf-editor` or a short cut to run programs hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> and type `gconf-editor` this will open up the configuration editor
2. Find `/apps/gnome-power-manager/actions/` by using the **+** icons and folders on the left sidebar, so first find "apps" then "gnome-power-manager" within the "apps" folder, and finally "actions" within that.
3. Within "actions"  look for `sleep_type_battery` and `sleep_type_ac` in the main window. Which in your case the value would be set to `suspend` double click suspend and change it to `hibernate` for which one you want to set to hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Since later versions of Ubuntu use `dconf` instead of `gconf`, [Mateo's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/113238/20358) is out-of-date. To edit these same settings in `dconf`, do the following:

1. First, run

   ```
    $ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power | grep sleep-inactive
   ```

and take note of the different values: there is a timeout and type for each of A/C power and battery power. The *type* is one of `'suspend'` or `'hibernate'`. The *timeout* is the number of seconds of inactivity before suspending.

2. In System Settings (`gnome-control-center`), choose power, and set the timeout to some unique value; I chose 2 hours (7200 seconds), since both `battery-timeout` and `ac-timeout` were set to disabled (0) previously.
3. Now, run the command in step 1 again. Check which timeout changed. For my *desktop* computer it was the *battery* timeout, so pay close attention.
4. Modify the "sleep" type which corresponds to the timeout you modified in step 2. Since step 2 modified the timeout for *battery*, I modified the sleep type for battery.

   ```
    $ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'hibernate'
   ```

Comment: Over four years later, these settings are still available in Ubuntu 20.04, but I was unable to understand the instructions before going through the process, again. Hopefully, my edits have clarified that.