# How can I make my PC hibernate when idle? 14.04

Tags: power-management, hibernate

I see that this was asked some time ago [for 11.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111486/how-can-i-make-my-pc-hibernate-when-idle?rq=1).

The answer there didn't help since the answer used gconf-editor to find a key called `/apps/gnome-power-manager/actions/`, which doesn't exist when I look in my install of 14.04.

This setting must be stored somewhere else?

Comment: You can install it with `sudo apt-get install gconf-editor`

Comment: Installed gconf-editor (the setting was not in there) and updated the question. Thanks TuKsn.

Comment: It may be somewhere in GConf. I didn't think ubuntu even had hibernate any more...

Comment: Perhaps you should first enable hibernate http://askubuntu.com/a/94963/265974

Comment: Hibernation is enabled already.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu Unity now uses **dconf** instead of **gconf**. Read [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/191013/354663) on how to modify settings.

The keys you are looking for are stored in `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power`.

For example

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'hibernate'
```

will change the idle action on AC power to `hibernate`.

You can still set the timeout via system settings ("System Settings"->"Power"->"Suspend when inactive for..."), this will **not** reset the type to 'suspend'.